# JavaScript QR-Code library (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I am searching for a js-library that lets me easily create QR-codes using pure JavaScript. I can find a couple of libs that are using jQuery as well like these two:

- http://larsjung.de/qrcode/
- http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/

Does anybody know another lib that does not use jQuery?!

Thanks, Nik

Comment: Here is one http://d-project.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/qrcode/index.html , but voting to close as "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" **edit** don't use the example's `document.write` though

Comment: I personally feel that closing questions like this is being pedantic. From the question it is clear what the OP is trying to solve and obviously does not want to re-invent the wheel so needs a tool or library recommendation. This question is not likely to attract spam and allowing people to answer it will help the OP and others.